# django: Downcasting automatically in multitable inheritance/polymorphic tables

Tags: django, polymorphism, multi-table-inheritance

I have something like this:

```
class Base(Model):
     ...
     def downcast(self):
         try:
             return self.childa
         except:
             pass
         try:
             return self.childb
         except:
             pass
         return self


class ChildA(Base):
     ....

class ChildB(Base):
     ....

class Foo(Model):
     child = ForeignKey(Base)
```

Whenever I have a Foo object, the child foreignkey is always an instance of Base - my understanding is that's how Django works.  For now I have added a downcast() method to Base (see above).  I don't mind hardcoding the possible derived types.

What I would like is to somehow centralize that downcast automatically in Foo.  I added this multi-table inheritance to existing code and I keep finding instances where the code really needs it downcast -- so I have to then manually downcast it locally in the code.

I was using the django-polymorphic package, but it is giving me some side effects I don't know how/nor want to deal with (like I can't delete rows - got some error about opts.pk being None deep in queryset code.)

So I've wondered -- would putting something in __init__() (after calling the base class init) be ok?  Are there side effects I'm not thinking of?   This seems like it could be a problem when creating new instances from scratch.

```
def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
    super(Base, self).__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
    self.child = self.child.downcast()
```

Should I just rename child?

```
class Foo(Model):
    child_poly = ForeignKey(Base)  # was child
    @property
    def child(self):
        return self.child_poly.downcast()
```

This could be a problem when creating Foo() from scratch.  I can't say Foo(child=c).

Is there a better approach?   Not looking for a generic polymorphic solution/mixin -- not after trying to debug django and finding that removing django-polymorphic fixed the deletion issue.

Comment: Which version of the django-polymorphic did you try? This one https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic seems to be fairly well maintained. If it was I would suggest you post the issue/bug you encountered. If you already did, my apologies.

Comment: You might want to try out the [InheritanceManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) form django-model-utils if downcasting is all you need.

Comment: It was  django_polymorphic-0.5.tar.gz.  I didn't file a bug -- would have liked to, but all I got was a stack trace in the django query code.  I traced it out and didn't feel I could really do justice to the bug with a proper description of what was going on except that I would get opts.pk is None when django was accessing opts.pk.name.

Comment: I'm going to retry django_polymorphic, now 5.3 I believe, and see if I can reproduce the problem again.  I really like that it just gives you the object you need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I went back to django-polymorphic and haven't had the issue I was having before again.